# AspectJ - count of loop iterations

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Can I get a number of loop iterations of any loop with AspectJ, or any aop approach, or any external approach to the class? Imagine loop with just incrementation of local variable(not method argument), or something like that, what you can't get through joinpoint. I know that isn't possible set joinpoint to local variable.

```
public int iterationsOfLoop() {
    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0, i<10; i++) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why did you think aop is the answer? Is that because you can't edit the source?

Comment: It's for profiling purpose and almost every metric, which I will mesure, is accessible through aop so it's reason of my question. I'm not think that aop is the best answer, but I searching for solutions and consider each other. I can edit source, so if you have any idea, solution I will learn and consider it. Thank you

Comment: Well, you could always implement a simple profiler with events to which these classes that you are profiling can subscribe (hence the code change). You can then raise those events and let the profiler profile the code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

most pointcut definitions can only be bound to method invocations, which sadly `++` is not. you may be able to use a `cflow` style pointcut, but that would bind to every instruction execution, and would not pick out the `++`. if you must use aspectj, then a better approach would be to use a `Counter` class with an increment method. or if you are not bound to aspectj, then using ASM, for static analysis, you should be able to pick out the bytecode `iinc` which i think is usually used in for loops, and insert custom bytecode to call and inform your custom aspect of the increment.

[bytecode definitions for java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)

[asm library for java](http://asm.ow2.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that its not possible with aspectJ.

There are other approaches, for example the libraries used for cobertura reporting in testing present you reports that counts the number of times the program goes through each line. These libraries uses some form or code instrumentation.

The most relevant cobertura libraries are probably clover, emma or cobertura, you can try to find some information about the techniques that this libraries uses and try to do something similar.

Not an easy task.

Comment: Code instrumentation is one of first solutions that I tried and it works, but I want avoid of change source, although it's not possible with this problem.